# how to get the auth token if the session in vcenter using POST Request

Tags: node.js, request, vcenter

I am trying to get the session token to access the VCenter.

I tried to get it via postman which worked without any issue with a basic auth. when I try to do the same in NodeJS, I get empty data.

here is my code

```
async function getListPolicy(url, username, password) {
    var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer.from(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
    var header = {
        Authorization: auth,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + '/rest/com/vmware/cis/session',
        headers: header,
    };
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(body);
            resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
```

In PostMan I only used the `authorization` with a `Basic Auth`. It returns a Value with the key and this is what I am trying to get.

Thank you very much.

EDIT: 
the file gets called here.

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const getPolicies = require('./getPolicies.js');

router.post("/getListPolicy", getListPolicy);

module.exports = router;


async function getListPolicy(req, res, next) {
    var url = "https://xxx/";
    var username = "administrator@vsphere.local";
    var password = "xxx";
    var token = await getPolicies.getListPolicy(url, username, password);
    res.json(token);
}
```

Comment: can you check with these options? `var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: url + '/rest/com/vmware/cis/session',
        headers: header,
        auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
}
    };` removing the auth from headers

Comment: Added as an answer.

Comment: can you post the error if any. Console log or dir the error. Also, do a reject if error. `if(error) reject(error)`

Comment: there isn't any... it answer nothings. just a blank ```[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Listening on port 8080!

 *blanks*            ..
 ```

Comment: wait a min, are you calling the `getListPolicy` from somewhere? some model or remote method? are you hitting the remote method?

Comment: Please post the context from where you are calling the policy function.. as well as are you hitting the route as well from explorer or postman

Comment: added the file where it iscalled. 
in postman it's very simple, i put the url + authorization: basic auth. and that's it

Comment: can you confirm that `getListPolicy(req, res, next) ` is actually getting called? by console logging something inside?

Comment: yes sir. if I put resolve("test"), test is sent to my front end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195807/discussion-between-lucky-simon-and-aritra-chakraborty).

Answer (score 1):

According to the `request` api, for `Basic` auth can you provide the `auth` key in the options. Also, you can specify in the url as well.

From the [`npm doc`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication):

```
request.get('http://some.server.com/', {
  'auth': {
    'user': 'username',
    'pass': 'password',
    'sendImmediately': false
  }
});
```

OR,

```
var username = 'username',
    password = 'password',
    url = 'http://' + username + ':' + password + '@some.server.com';

request({url: url}, function (error, response, body) {
   // Do more stuff with 'body' here
});
```

Comment: accually this didn't work. I don't resolve anything. and the print was simply the header ^^'